# Retrieve fields from SQL Server 2012 in visualstudio 2012 (VB) result = __Page

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I made a simple script to get values from my SQL Server database into a label in visual studio.
It worked well, then I came back to it and every time I tried to get a result it just gives me __Page instead of the targeted value. I didn't change anything so I can't work out why it's broken.
Here's my code, if you could tell me where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it!

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("data source=HTZC91RC705H;database=AppForm;uid=sa;pwd=xxx;")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM dbo.AppForm", conn)

    conn.Open()
    Dim SchoolAddress As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    conn.Close()

    lblID.Text = ID
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Should be `lblID.Text = SchoolAddress`. But the logic of the name is beyond me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
 lblID.Text = ID
```

assigns the [property ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.id.aspx) of the Page to the label not the value of the field ID retrieved by your query. That value is in the SchoolAddress variable, so, apart from the unexplicable name the correct code should be

```
 lblID.Text = SchoolAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

In `lblID.Text = ID` where does the `ID` come from? It definitely does not contain anything returned by your SQL query; I would assume you're assigning the value of the `ID` property of your `Page` object here. Try `lblID.Text = SchoolAddress` instead.